# Match audio duration when joining multiple tracks

Tags: matlab, audio

I have a program that combines audio tracks together, the current system I have is that I can write two audio tracks and make them play simultaneously. The problem I am having is that it only plays for the duration of the shortest track, so for instance:

Track 1's duration = 2:00

Track 2's duration = 1:12

It will only play for `1:12` when I want it to play for `2:00` (the whole length). What's the best way to go about solving this issue?

My solution so far:

```
length = min([length(s1), length(s2)]);

s1 = s1(1:length);
s2 = s2(1:length);
s3 = s1 + s2;
```

Comment: Either pad the shorter track so it's the same length or use indexing to add the shorter track to the desired segment of the longer one.

Answer (score 0):

First of  all don't use function name "length" as to define new variable, You will not be able to use it as function in the next statement.
Second, when you play multiple tracks you want to be able to do some kind of sync in the beginning, so i added for you this option.

The solution is this:

```
s1=[ 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1 ];
s2=[ 0.1, 0.4 ];

s1_pad_delay=8; s1_pad_after=5;
s2_pad_delay=4; s2_pad_after=3;

s1_len=s1_pad_delay+length(s1)+s1_pad_after;
s2_len=s2_pad_delay+length(s2)+s2_pad_after;
mix_len=max(s1_len,s2_len);

s1_padded=[ zeros(1,s1_pad_delay), s1, zeros(1,mix_len-length(s1)-s1_pad_delay) ];
s2_padded=[ zeros(1,s2_pad_delay), s2, zeros(1,mix_len-length(s2)-s2_pad_delay) ];

mix=s1_padded+s2_padded
```