# Max value is not being recognised

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to combine two audio signals but cannot do so without using a `min` operator. I need the audio tracks to play simultaneously, which is a solution I currently have but have a problem. It only plays for the duration of the shortest track, this is my code so far:

```
mLength = min([length(s1), length(s2)]);

s1 = s1(1:mLength);
s2 = s2(1:mLength);
s3 = s1 + s2;
```

`s1` might be 6 seconds long and `s2` might be 10 seconds long. Combining them will give me a track at a duration of 6 seconds.

I essentially need to change the `min` to `max`. Upon doing this, it gives me the error `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

Anyone know how I can do this? Such a trivial problem that is taking so long to try and solve, thank you!

Comment: Why couldn't this be an edit to [this morning's question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381270/match-audio-duration-when-joining-multiple-tracks)?

Comment: @excaza apologies but it was lost and I felt it was easier just to reformat it. Been working on this since this morning

Comment: I would highly recommend taking the time to read through the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section again. This is not the first time you've disregarded SO's guidelines and continuing to do so will likely lead to a suspension or ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
mLength = max(length(s1), length(s2));
s1(mLength+1,:) = 0;
s2(mLength+1,:) = 0;
s3 = s1(1:mLength,:) + s2(1:mLength,:);
```

This assigns a zero at the maximum position plus 1. The effect of this on the longest signal is just to append a zero. On the shortest one it automatically pads with zeros as needed. Now that the two signals have the same length they can be added, ignoring the last extra zero.

Comment: Cheers for the quick reply and simple response. I'm afraid your solution gives me `Attempt to grow array along ambiguous dimension.` Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh, they are stereo, right? Wait a minute

Comment: @Paji.R Please see now